# What is the opposite of None?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this chunk of code in spark

```
val stuff = MyFunction(
    start=new LocalDate(2019, 7, 1),
    end=new LocalDate(2019, 7, 3),
    discreteCol = None
).persist
```

The function reads and filters from a parquet file. Is there an antonym to None?

I'd like to accept all results in the discreteCol. The function won't let me omit the variable, so I want to just say it should take any value without having to enumerate each of them.

Comment: What do you mean by this? You can have your discreenCol to be an Optional type and you can either have Some(YourObject) or None ad value when you call the MyFunction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class called `Option`. It has two subclasses: `None` and `Some`. This class is for handling null values. 
If you want your method to accept any class the your `discreteCol` type should be `Option[Any]`. Then when passing values to the function, you should send them as a some value. Like this: `Some(yourValue)`.